# Angular 8 data binding : inject image path into html component

Tags: html, angular, image, data-binding

I'm getting data from service and I want to inject icon path into a html img tag :

```
export class GiftChecksComponent implements OnInit {

  types: GiftType[]
  giftCardType: GiftType;
  typesSubcription: Subscription
  serverUrl = environment.serverUrl


  constructor(private cartService: CartService, private router: Router, private http: HttpClient, private giftTypeService: GiftTypeService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.typesSubcription = this.giftTypeService.getGiftTypesList().subscribe(result => {
      this.types = result as GiftType[];
    })
  }
}



<div class="available-checks" *ngIf="!(types === null)">
    <div class="row checks-list">
      <div class="col-md-3" *ngFor="let type of types">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-8 logo-container justify-content-center">
                <img class="card-logo" src="../../../assets/images/logo-gold.svg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="col-4 icon-container justify-content-center text-center">
                <img [src]="serverUrl+ / +type?.image" alt="" style="width: 50px;height: 50px;">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row desc-title-c">
              <p class="desc-title">Chèque cadeau</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row type-c">
              <p class="check-type">{{type.type}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="offer-container">
              <p class="offer">{{type.designation}}</p>
              <p class="price">{{type.amount}}€</p>
            </div>
            <div class="">
              <button class="btn btn-footer" (click)="addGiftToCart(type)">Ajouter au panier</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

the object's attributes called correctly but the item.icon not displayed and I got undefined  : "http://localhost:8000/undefined"

Comment: I think the issue is with this binding: `serverUrl+ / +type?.image`. Shouldn't it be `serverUrl + '/' + type?.image`?

Comment: And also you can try changing the binding to `[attr.src]` instead of `[src]` after fixing the typo.

Comment: not working @HarunYilmaz